# How to split an element with mixed content?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

This is the structure of my XML-document:

```
<root>
    <txt>text here http <b>may</b> occur <i>many<sup>TM</sup></i> times.</txt>
</root>
```

After processing it should look like this:

```
<root>
    <txt>text here </txt>
    <url>http</url>
    <txt> <b>may</b> occur <i>many<sup>TM</sup></i> times.</txt>
</root>
```

(Linebreaks added manually for clarity.)

The following template is getting it "almost" right, but with the parts i commented out it is of course not correct:

```
<xsl:template match="txt/text()[contains(.,'http')]">
    <xsl:variable name="here" select="." />

    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="htt[^ ]+">

        <xsl:matching-substring>
                            <!-- this would solve all problems: 
                             let's just close the txt-element for a second ...
                <xsl:text></txt></xsl:text>
                            -->
            <xsl:element name="uri">
                <xsl:attribute name="href" select="." />
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
                            <!-- ... and open the txt-element again: nice!
                <xsl:text<txt></xsl:text>
                             -->    
        </xsl:matching-substring>

        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                         <txt> <!-- not needed for the fake -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                         </txt> <!-- dito -->
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Instead i used additional templates to wrap all the other parts of txt into txt-elements, like this. The result is also valid but not really usable:

```
<xsl:template match="txt">
    <!-- only needed für the fake solution above:
            <xsl:copy> -->
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    <!-- </xsl:copy> -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="txt/text()[not(contains(.,'http'))]">
    <txt>
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </txt>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="txt/*" name="element_wrapper">
    <txt>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </xsl:copy>
    </txt>
</xsl:template>
```

the result is ugly, but valid:

```
<root>
    <txt>text here </txt>
    <url>http</url>
    <txt> </txt>
    <txt><b>may</b></txt>
    <txt> occur </txt>
    <txt><i>many<sup>TM</sup></i></txt>
    <txt> times.</txt>
</root>
```

(again, linebreaks added by me)

All the other "solutions" i have seen so far split at element borders or tokenize the strings only, but they don't split in the middle of the text. Maybe my working solution can be reformatted by removing all adjacent `</txt><txt>` but i don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: Well, as for "my working solution can be reformatted by removing all adjacent </txt><txt> but i don't know how to achieve that", you can of course store the result of your transformation in a variable and then simply use `<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::txt)">` to identify adjacent `txt` elements and merge them.

Comment: You've given one input document, and the output for that document, but you haven't stated any general rules that indicate what the output should be for a different input. The only way we know that you want to recognize "http" and "https" and not "ftp" is by looking at your code, but we know your code is incorrect, so we can't be expected to reverse engineer your requirements by reading it.

Comment: My question was more about the splitting of the txt element. What pattern is detected ist arbitrary. Martin Honnen understood it correctly. In general terms I'm trying to split the txt-element at some position in the text-content. At this position a different, "intermittent" element needs to be added.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two steps using modes, one that use `xsl:analyze-string` on text nodes to transform `http` or variants into `url` element and a second that then uses `for-each-group group-starting-with="url"` to split:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="txt">
        <xsl:variable name="links">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates mode="insert-links"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$links/node()" mode="extract-urls"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" mode="insert-links" priority="5">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="http[s]?">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <url href="{.}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </url>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[url]" mode="extract-urls">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-starting-with="url">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="self::url">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:element name="{name(..)}">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group() except ." mode="extract-urls"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:element name="{name(..)}">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That transforms the input

```
<txt>text here http <b>may</b> occur <i>many<sup>TM</sup></i> times and https as well.</txt>
```

into the output

```
<txt>text here </txt><url href="http">http</url><txt> <b>may</b> occur <i>many<sup>TM</sup></i> times and </txt><url href="https">https</url><txt> as well.</txt>
```